# How to reach the declared variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to reach the variable's header .. for example in Redux Framework WordPress plugin there's a variable [redux.args.opt_name] .. How to reach the define line of this variable?

Another Question: What is the two single quotes in 'opt_name' variable mean ??

```
data: {
     action: redux.args.opt_name + "_ajax_save",
     nonce: $nonce,
     'opt_name': redux.args.opt_name,
     data: $data
},
```

The complete file [redux.js](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/master/ReduxCore/assets/js/redux.js)

Comment: What do you mean by "variable's header"?

Comment: Where's the define line like .. var x = 'some data';

Comment: You want to find the variable that contains the `redux.args.opt_name` value? Why, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The "define line" is not in your snippet.

Comment: You want to find the declaration of the `redux` variable? Why? Do you want to reverse engineer the library?

Comment: I just need to understand something new, How to pass a value to [redux.args.opt_name] and what is [redux.args.opt_name] .. I tried to find a class called [redux] and variable called [args] but I didn't find it .. Is that a variable?? and how to pass a value inside it??

Comment: Why do you keep putting brackets around things? That has a specific meaning in JavaScript, so unless you're indicating that all of these variables are inside arrays, best to leave it out. If you want to mark something as code in a comment, use tick marks (`\``) around the whole word/phrase.

Comment: I do NOT need to modify anything .. I need to make something like this in my own project

Comment: You can take a look for the redux.js file (https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework/blob/master/ReduxCore/assets/js/redux.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variable passed using WordPress function ( localize_script )

```
wp_localize_script(
     'redux-js',
     'redux',
     $this->parent->localize_data
);

wp_enqueue_script( 'redux-js' ); // Enque the JS now
```

$this->parent->localize_data is an array

```
Array (
[args] => Array
    (
        [opt_name] => 'redux_demo'

    )
)
```